# Accessing comments and/or TRIVIA files in XPath

Tags: xpath, abstract-syntax-tree, sonarqube

i have got some trouble, using the XPath. (Later i want to add my expression on SonarQube to rule of xpath pattern so i can create my own rules there. But SonarQube is not required yet)

I want to create a rule which throws exception if a project was analyzed and something special was written in the comments (e.g. "ERROR") of my java projects (e.g. myXPathTry.java).

I am testing all my expressions with this [SSLR Toolkit](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java/sslr-java-toolkit/1.5). Just need to download it and execute it.

Usage is simple: add your code on the left, click "Parse Source Code" right under the box. Then add your xpath rule in the box on the bottom and finally click "Evaluate XPath". Result should be marked. You are also allowed to view the automatic created XML for your source code if you click the xml button above the right box.

**My problem is**: all the comments are saved in "unaccessable" TRIVIA path (as you can see in the AST). I can access all other things and check against there values and parameters, but not this TRIVIA stuff. (JavaCode, AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) and XML are added below.)

Do you know a way how i  can get access to the comments? 
Thanks for your Help! :)

```
Already tested: 
neighter //*/comment() , nor //*/TOKEN/TRIVIA does have any effect. 
//*/TOKEN works and has affect, but does not contain the needed information.
```

Java Code:

```
public class MyXPathTry{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Just to have some code");
        //This is a comment
        /* This is a second comment */
        /* This is a second comment with ERROR*/
    }
}
```

[image: AST-Image]

In the AST the blue line (RWING, if image is not visable) was selectet after i clicked on any comment on the left of the toolkit. Path downwards was not opend by default. I opened RWING and the TOKEN subfolder by myself, just do show you what i mean with TRIVIA files)

```
Toolkit Auto-Created XML:
<compilationUnit tokenValue="public" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0">
  <typeDeclaration tokenValue="public" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0">
    <modifier tokenValue="public" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0">
      <PUBLIC tokenValue="public" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="public" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="0"/>
      </PUBLIC>
    </modifier>
    <classDeclaration tokenValue="class" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="7">
      <CLASS tokenValue="class" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="7">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="class" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="7"/>
      </CLASS>
      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="MyXPathTry" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="13">
        <TOKEN tokenValue="MyXPathTry" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="13"/>
      </IDENTIFIER>
      <classBody tokenValue="{" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="23">
        <LWING tokenValue="{" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="23">
          <TOKEN tokenValue="{" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="23"/>
        </LWING>
        <classBodyDeclaration tokenValue="public" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="4">
          <modifier tokenValue="public" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="4">
            <PUBLIC tokenValue="public" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="4">
              <TOKEN tokenValue="public" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="4"/>
            </PUBLIC>
          </modifier>
          <modifier tokenValue="static" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="11">
            <STATIC tokenValue="static" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="11">
              <TOKEN tokenValue="static" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="11"/>
            </STATIC>
          </modifier>
          <memberDecl tokenValue="void" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="18">
            <VOID tokenValue="void" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="18">
              <TOKEN tokenValue="void" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="18"/>
            </VOID>
            <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="main" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="23">
              <TOKEN tokenValue="main" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="23"/>
            </IDENTIFIER>
            <voidMethodDeclaratorRest tokenValue="(" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="27">
              <formalParameters tokenValue="(" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="27">
                <LPAR tokenValue="(" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="27">
                  <TOKEN tokenValue="(" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="27"/>
                </LPAR>
                <formalParameterDecls tokenValue="String" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="28">
                  <type tokenValue="String" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="28">
                    <classType tokenValue="String" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="28">
                      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="String" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="28">
                        <TOKEN tokenValue="String" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="28"/>
                      </IDENTIFIER>
                    </classType>
                    <dim tokenValue="[" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="34">
                      <LBRK tokenValue="[" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="34">
                        <TOKEN tokenValue="[" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="34"/>
                      </LBRK>
                      <RBRK tokenValue="]" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="35">
                        <TOKEN tokenValue="]" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="35"/>
                      </RBRK>
                    </dim>
                  </type>
                  <formalParametersDeclsRest tokenValue="args" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="37">
                    <variableDeclaratorId tokenValue="args" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="37">
                      <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="args" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="37">
                        <TOKEN tokenValue="args" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="37"/>
                      </IDENTIFIER>
                    </variableDeclaratorId>
                  </formalParametersDeclsRest>
                </formalParameterDecls>
                <RPAR tokenValue=")" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="41">
                  <TOKEN tokenValue=")" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="41"/>
                </RPAR>
              </formalParameters>
              <methodBody tokenValue="{" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="42">
                <block tokenValue="{" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="42">
                  <LWING tokenValue="{" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="42">
                    <TOKEN tokenValue="{" tokenLine="2" tokenColumn="42"/>
                  </LWING>
                  <blockStatements tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="1">
                    <blockStatement tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="1">
                      <statement tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="1">
                        <expressionStatement tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="1">
                          <statementExpression tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="1">
                            <expression tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="1">
                              <primary tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="1">
                                <qualifiedIdentifier tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="1">
                                  <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="1">
                                    <TOKEN tokenValue="System" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="1"/>
                                  </IDENTIFIER>
                                  <DOT tokenValue="." tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="7">
                                    <TOKEN tokenValue="." tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="7"/>
                                  </DOT>
                                  <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="out" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="8">
                                    <TOKEN tokenValue="out" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="8"/>
                                  </IDENTIFIER>
                                  <DOT tokenValue="." tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="11">
                                    <TOKEN tokenValue="." tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="11"/>
                                  </DOT>
                                  <IDENTIFIER tokenValue="println" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="12">
                                    <TOKEN tokenValue="println" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="12"/>
                                  </IDENTIFIER>
                                </qualifiedIdentifier>
                                <identifierSuffix tokenValue="(" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="19">
                                  <arguments tokenValue="(" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="19">
                                    <LPAR tokenValue="(" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="19">
                                      <TOKEN tokenValue="(" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="19"/>
                                    </LPAR>
                                    <expression tokenValue=""Just to have some code"" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="20">
                                      <primary tokenValue=""Just to have some code"" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="20">
                                        <literal tokenValue=""Just to have some code"" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="20">
                                          <LITERAL tokenValue=""Just to have some code"" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="20">
                                            <TOKEN tokenValue=""Just to have some code"" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="20"/>
                                          </LITERAL>
                                        </literal>
                                      </primary>
                                    </expression>
                                    <RPAR tokenValue=")" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="44">
                                      <TOKEN tokenValue=")" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="44"/>
                                    </RPAR>
                                  </arguments>
                                </identifierSuffix>
                              </primary>
                            </expression>
                          </statementExpression>
                          <SEMI tokenValue=";" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="45">
                            <TOKEN tokenValue=";" tokenLine="3" tokenColumn="45"/>
                          </SEMI>
                        </expressionStatement>
                      </statement>
                    </blockStatement>
                  </blockStatements>
                  <RWING tokenValue="}" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="4">
                    <TOKEN tokenValue="}" tokenLine="7" tokenColumn="4"/>
                  </RWING>
                </block>
              </methodBody>
            </voidMethodDeclaratorRest>
          </memberDecl>
        </classBodyDeclaration>
        <RWING tokenValue="}" tokenLine="8" tokenColumn="0">
          <TOKEN tokenValue="}" tokenLine="8" tokenColumn="0"/>
        </RWING>
      </classBody>
    </classDeclaration>
  </typeDeclaration>
  <EOF tokenValue="" tokenLine="8" tokenColumn="1"/>
</compilationUnit>
```

.

Comment: This is a `sonarqube` related question, why did you remove the tag?

Comment: Because I was not sure in which way it affects SonarQube. The Toolkit says something about SonarQube, but you can use it without. And if it is working in the toolkit, it will also working in SonarQube (V.3.7) later as well. SonarQube is not affecting this xpath expression so far, i thought. But i add the SonarQube tag back.

Comment: I don't see anything that resembles references to those comments in the XML you've shown us. If it isn't there, XPath can't access it.

Comment: @keshlam I think the question is more "how to get it in". I've looked at the source code for the SSLR Toolkit for a bit, especially [the `AstXmlPrinter` class](https://github.com/SonarSource/sslr/blob/master/sslr-core/src/main/java/com/sonar/sslr/impl/ast/AstXmlPrinter.java#L67), but it's not conclusive. The comment nodes are in the AST after all, for some reason they are not output.

Comment: I'd take that up with the authors of the tool, then.

Comment: @keshlam i also noticed that. That was the main reason for me, why i asked you guys for help. But it seems like there is no help for me now. Do you guys know where the best place is to ask the developers for a solution in the next version? I am not sure who would be the right person to ask. Thank you a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. For your information the ability to write custom rules in XPath will be dropped in favor of writing them in Java.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But I must say: I am not experienced in writing my own xpath rule in Java. And the problem to enter comments would be the same for me. The easiest way for me will be: Ignore the comments the same way XPath in Sonar does :D

Thanks for your help!